# Test suite to generate page faults and LLC miss events

Tags: virtual, benchmarking, memory-profiling

I need to profile a virtual machine memory access in terms of the number of page
faults per second generated and number of last level cache miss encountered per
second. Is there a standard test suite that helps me achieve this?

Below I describe the exact scenario I need to achieve:

1. Run a program / test suite on a virtual machine to generate enormous number 
   of page faults.
2. Run a program / test suite on a virtual machine to generate large number of 
   last level cache misses.
3. Monitor the number of page faults per second and last level cache miss per 
   second on the virtual machine.
4. Monitor the corresponding number of page faults & last level cache miss on 
   hosting bare metal machine.

Beyond this is the set of analysis results I need to generate.

Query 1:
Is there a standard test suite which helps me achieve my objective? Please point
out the reference if so. I browsed through SPEC benchmarks, but I did not seem to
find anything of much use to my work.

Query 2:
IF there is no such suite, is there a way I can write a program to emulate the
scenario described above?

Any pointers in either directions are appreciated.

Thanks!